# Elastic Search: Zero results for Geodistance filter

Tags: elasticsearch, geospatial

I am using elasticSearch's Java API. I want to search for posts that are around a certain point. Thus a post has a coordinates field. Here's my code to achieve the mapping:

```
String mappingString =
        "{"
        +    "\"posts\" : {"
        +        "\"properties\" : {"
        +            "\"coordinates\" : {"
        +                "\"type\" : \"geo_point\""
        +            "}"
        +        "}"
        +    "}"
        +"}";     

Client.admin().indices().preparePutMapping("posts").setType("posts").setSource(mappingString).execute().actionGet ();
```

I verified with ElasticSearch Head that I indeed have posts in the index that should pass the filter. A post looks like this:

```
{
"link":"http://instagram.com/p/hBV...EjHk/",
"pictureURL":"http://distilleryimage0.s3.amazonaws.com/b5887...8f21ef_6.jpg",
"userID":"358...3",
"commentsCount":0,
"likesCount":2,
"coordinates":{"lat":32.519634,"lon":33.414997},
"userName":"tuvs...yahde",
"nGrams":[],
"id":"IG_5948523...879524_358...163",
"indexDate":1385131949
}
```

This would be stored in an index named "posts". However, I do have different types in that index, all of which share the coordinates, id and indexDate fields, but might differ in the other fields (That is because some posts have pictures, others have text, others have both).

Finally, here's the code I use for querying ElasticSearch:

```
GeoDistanceFilterBuilder gdFilter =   FilterBuilders.geoDistanceFilter("posts.coordinates")
    .point(lat, lon)
    .distance(distanceInMeters, DistanceUnit.METERS)
    .optimizeBbox("memory")                    
    .geoDistance(GeoDistance.ARC);             

SearchResponse response = Client.prepareSearch("posts")
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
    .setFilter(gdFilter)
    .setSize(100)
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

The issue is, that whatever values I use for the variables in the query and the filter, I always get zero results. Can someone see, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `.point(lat, lon)`.

Comment: You are correct. However that unfortunately does not solve my problem. I switched these two parameters 10 times by now (that's probably where the error above came from), trying it with different combinations for the other parameters. But still no luck...

Comment: Can you provide the entire example then, with your test data?

Comment: I added more context. (Sorry for the delay.)

Comment: Hmmm, it mnow looks to me like the issue is that I have an index which has different types in it. If I rename all types to the name of the index it works, otherwise it does not... Well, that not how I understood that indices and types should work. I f this is really the case, I would have to re-architecture this project quite a bit.

Comment: Please, take a look at this working example. I hope this will help https://gist.github.com/imotov/dbfe693a761fbd2ab892

Comment: Thanks to your example it is working now! My error was here: `preparePutMapping("posts").setType("posts")` My index name is "posts", but I have different types in that index. It seems to me now that I have to define a mapping for each type. That's quite a few mappings in my case, and dangerous because new types that go into the "posts" index might be introduced at a later stage. Is there a way to define a mapping for an index rather than a type?

Comment: Yes, you can add [default mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-mapper.html#_dynamic_default_mappings) that will be automatically copied to all newly created types.